# Typo3 flow validation error

Tags: php, validation, typo3, typo3-flow

I have problem with validation in Typo3 flow.

I'm doing POST request for REST and this is action in controller for it.

```
/**
     * Create Customer
     *
     *
     * @param int $clientId
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $phone
     * @param string $mail
     * @param string  $zip
     * @param string $city
     * @param int countryId
     * @return string
     */
    public function createAction($clientId, $name, $phone, $mail, $zip, $city, $countryId) {
        try{
            $this->checkAccessArgs();
            $client = $this->clientCustomerRepository->getReference('\Shopbox\API\Domain\Model\Client',$clientId);
            $country = $this->clientCustomerRepository->getReference('\Shopbox\API\Domain\Model\Country',$countryId);
            $newCustomer = new ClientCustomer();
            $newCustomer->setClient($client);
            $newCustomer->setCountry($country);
            $newCustomer->setName($name);
            $newCustomer->setPhone($phone);
            $newCustomer->setMail($mail);
            $newCustomer->setZip($zip);
            $newCustomer->setCity($city);
            $newCustomer->setCrdate(time());
            $newCustomer->setTstamp(time());
            $newCustomer->setDeleted(0);
            $newCustomer->setHidden(0);
            $customerValidator = $this->validatorResolver->getBaseValidatorConjunction('\Shopbox\API\Domain\Model\ClientCustomer');
            $result = $customerValidator->validate($newCustomer);
            if($result->hasErrors()){
                throw new \Exception($result->getFirstError()->getMessage() ,$result->getFirstError()->getCode());
            }
            $this->clientCustomerRepository->add($newCustomer);
            $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
            $this->response->setStatus(201);
            $this->view->setVariablesToRender(array(self::JSON_RESPONSE_ROOT_SINGLE));
            $this->view->assign(self::JSON_RESPONSE_ROOT_SINGLE,
                array(self::JSON_RESPONSE_ROOT_SINGLE=> $newCustomer)
            );
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->response->setStatus($e->getCode());
            return $this->assignError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is how I validate in Model.

```
/**
     * @var string
     * @Flow\Validate(type="EmailAddress")
     */
    protected $mail;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Flow\Validate(type="StringLength", options={ "minimum"=8, "maximum"=8 })
     */
    protected $phone;
```

Error that I get is this.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object in
>   /path_to_project/flow2/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/path_to_Controller.php
>   on line 87

If I don't put validation inside action function then I get validation message but it saves to database what it shouldn't do.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result->hasErrors()) {
```

Here your object has errors is true, because at least one of its properties have errors (parent is notified).

But.. parent doesn't store it in his errors array - property does - so.. `$result->getErrors()` is empty same as `$result->getFirstError()`..

To get access from parent to properties errors you can use:

```
$errors = $result->getFlattenedErrors();
```

or

```
$result->forProperty('name')->getFirstError();
```